# How do I create an "optional" argument in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a simple Python class named "Bag":

```
class Bag:
def __init__(self, items=None):
    if self.items == None:
        self.items = defaultdict()
    else:
        temp_dict = defaultdict()
        for key in self.items:
            temp_dict[key] += 1
        self.items = temp_dict
```

The variable **items** takes in a list of objects, such as:

```
['d','a','b','d','c','b','d']
```

From there, "def __init__(self, items=None)" will either:

1. Initialize **items** as an empty **defaultdict**, if nothing was passed into **items**, or
2. Initialize the passed in argument, if a list of objects were passed into **items**.

For example, this should work:

```
b = Bag()
```

The absence of an argument should be fine, as **items** is set, by default, to **_None**.

However, this always raises an exception(from a script that checks for errors):

```
*Error: b = Bag() raised exception AttributeError: 'Bag' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I want to initialize **Bag()** without putting a passing an argument into **items**.

Hope everything is clear, tell me if it isn't.

Any ideas or anything wrong with the code?

Comment: I think you can do `def __init__(self, items=None):` which will still allow `items` to optionally be set when you want it to be set

Comment: @downshift I made the changes you've suggested, but it still gives me the same exception.

Comment: my apologies, put `self.items = items` as the first line after `def __init__(..`

Comment: Did you notice that you started comparing `self.items` before even defining it? Your error is that `if` coming before the assignation

Comment: @monchitos82 Yeah, I noticed that from labheshr's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Bag(object):

def __init__(self, items=None):
    self.items = items or list()
    if not self.items:
        self.items = defaultdict()
    else:
        temp_dict = defaultdict()
        for key in self.items:
            temp_dict[key] += 1
        self.items = temp_dict
```

I made a few corrections:

1) create `self.items` and initialize with `items`
2) compare with None using `is None` , or simply `not self.items`, since empty lists evaluate to `False`

Comment: Beware of the mutable default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: Please never use a mutable value as a default for an argument. It is cerated a t function creation time and _shared across invocations,_ so if your function happens to update `items`, the next call will see it. Use `None` as default, then use `items or []` (or `iems or defaultdict(int)` in your case) when accessing it.

Comment: @labheshr Thank you! I made the changes, and it worked. I realized that I never initialized self.items before the if-else statement.

Answer (score 2):

`'Bag' object has no attribute 'items'` means: somewhere in the `Bag`'s method you're accessing `self.items` that has not been defined.

And indeed you do. In the constructor, you write: `if self.items == None:` *before* you make the first assignment to `self.items`, thus creating it.

I think it's a typo, and you meant `if items is None:`, referring to the parameter.

This code can be simplified, though. My take:

```
import collections  # Batteries included.

...
def __init__(self, items=None):
    if not items:  # Covers both None and empty list.
        self.items = {}
    else:
        self.items = collections.Counter(items)
```

This can be simplified even more:

```
     ...
     self.items = collections.Counter(items or [])
```

If you strictly want a to use a `defaultdict`, you can:

```
     self.items = collections.defauldict(int, collections.Counter(items or []))
```

(Note that `defaultdict()` without an argument makes rather little sense.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would love to use Counter, but, sadly, the project I'm working on requires using "defaultdict".

Comment: Taking out the extra suggestion this solves your question without "altering" your initial code

Comment: Updated my answer.